# Get users info from nextcloud api

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using the [node-nextcloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-nextcloud) module, how to get emails for all users from an array? For example, the nc.users.get() method works with one userID, but what about when it's a hundred userIDs? I tried to work with the method directly and through a loop, but the result is not satisfactory.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const NextCloud = require('node-nextcloud');
var nc = NextCloud("Domain", "User", "Password");
var arr = []

//get users id into array
nc.users.list(null, (err, ocs)=> {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    arr = ocs.data.users
    console.log(arr)
})
//try to get email for each id from array
nc.users.get('' , (err, ocs)=>{
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    arr.forEach(email  => {
        console.log(ocs.data.email)
    })
})
```

Comment: Why is the result "not satisfactory"

Comment: @TommyBs Because the nc.users.get() method works well for one userID, but what about when you have hundreds of userIDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve the result in the following way:

```
nc.users.list(null, (err, ocs)=> {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    arr = ocs.data.users
    //console.log(arr)


    arr.forEach((item, index, array) => {
        nc.users.get(`${item}`, (err, ocs) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            console.log(ocs.data.email);
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with next cloud but it would appear to me you want to use the `list` method first to get all the user ids, then loop through the result from that list to get each user. Depending on the number of users it could be quite a lengthly operation. You're currently calling two asynchronous methods but the second one doesn't wait for the first one to finish. As I say I'm not familiar with next cloud but the below is a rough stab at what you might need

```
async function getUsers() {
let users = await nc.users.list();
const userEmails = await Promise.all(users.map(async (userId) => {
    const user = await nc.users.get(userId);
    return user.email;

}))

console.log("user emails", userEmails);
}

getUsers();
```

Comment: Thanks for your participation. I managed to achieve the result in the following way.